# Header disappears when scrolling with Textarea

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a small Notepad application online using just CSS and HTML. For some reason, my application creates a weird glitch where you scroll down in the text area far enough and scroll back up to find the header is missing.

https://jsfiddle.net/2v7ptadh/
How can I fix this issue?


This is the CSS code that is creating the error. If you want to view the full code, click on the JS Fiddle link above.

```
html,
body {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #888;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

div#header {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(100, 125, 130);
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(150, 175, 140);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(60, 48, 75);
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(80, 84, 90);
    background: #bbb;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    z-index: 4
}

div#app {
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
textarea#app-input {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 20px;
    resize: none;
}

textarea::selection {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Video of issue: http://recordit.co/2AxYmb9XxV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to set `html/body` to `height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;` then `#app` shouldn't be `height: 100%` - change that to `height: calc(100% - 40px)` where `40px` is the header height. That will keep everything in the viewport.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
html,
body {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #888;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

div#header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(100, 125, 130);
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(150, 175, 140);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(60, 48, 75);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(80, 84, 90);
  background: #bbb;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  z-index: 4
}

div#app {
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea#app-input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 20px;
  resize: none;
}

textarea::selection {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">ONLINE NOTEPAD</div>
<div id="app">
  <textarea id="app-input"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing overflow-y:hidden from html and body

```
html,
body {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #888;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Tested it out without overflow-y on JSFiddle